# RESTful service deployed on JBoss does not respond

Tags: java, scala, maven, jboss, resteasy

I have a problem testing a simple Restful service on JBoss.

I have built the project and deployed to JBoss fine. This is my Deployer written using Java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class Deployer extends Application {

}
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<web-app>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.mxyy.orderservice.deploy.Deployer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/orderservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my Restful service interface written in Scala:

```
@Provider
@Path("/customers")
trait ICustomerService {
  @POST
  @Consumes(Array("application/xml"))
  def createCustomer(is: InputStream): Response

  @GET
  @Path("{id}")
  @Produces(Array("application/xml"))
  def getCustomer(@PathParam("id") id: Int): StreamingOutput

  @PUT
  @Path("{id}")
  @Consumes(Array("application/xml"))
  def updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") id: Int, is: InputStream): Unit
}
```

This interface is implemented.

After I deployed to JBoss, I tried to access the service by typing:

```
 http://localhost:8080/orderservice/customers/1
```

The browser respond with

```
HTTP Status 404 - /orderservice/customers/1    

type Status report    
message /orderservice/customers/1    
description The requested resource (/orderservice/customers/1) is not available.
```

Can someone point out what I did wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think everything is fine there except a small mistake that's "/".
just edit as:

```
@Provider
@Path("/customers")
trait ICustomerService {
@POST
@Consumes(Array("application/xml"))
def createCustomer(is: InputStream): Response

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(Array("application/xml"))
def getCustomer(@PathParam("id") id: Int): StreamingOutput

@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes(Array("application/xml"))
def updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") id: Int, is: InputStream): Unit
}
```

Inform me if it works. :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem :(